# How to make php script fill remote forms and submit?

Tags: php

To make this short, I will show what I need exactly.
Here is the site, it shows some info about game stats once entered username and region.

```
http://riot.control-c.ir/
http://riot.control-c.ir/Summoner/EUW/26233693
```

How can I make remote submitting these forms to parse pages for different users?

Comment: I think you must read this: http://anders.com/projects/sysadmin/formPostHijacking/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis can be done by copying the same http request that the remote form makes when it submits.

See the following form,

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<input type=text name="username" />
<input type=text name="password" />
<input type=submit name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When this form is submitted there is an http request sent to `submit.php` on the remote host with post method. and in the body these fields reside.

```
username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&submit=Submit
```

The http request looks like

```
POST submit.php
Host: remotehost.com
Accpet: */*
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 43

username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&submit=Submit
```

All you have to do is mimic this request.

[Curl](http://php.net/curl) is a popular library for this task.